# Adding partition to existing table in mysql gives wrong result

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have created employee table in mysql with below details.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INT ,
  username varchar(50) ,
  store_id INT ,
   name VARCHAR(20)
);

-> insert into employee values(1,"ajay@gmail.com",79, "Ajay verma");
-> insert into employee values(2,"rahul@gmail.com",85, "rahul shaikh");
->insert into employee values(3,"vikas@gmail.com",302, "vikas malhotra");
```

Now I add range partition to above existing employee table having above records.

```
Alter table employee
PARTITION BY range columns(store_id)(
PARTITION p0 VALUES less than (100),
PARTITION p1 VALUES less than (200),
PARTITION p2 VALUES less than (300),
PARTITION p3 VALUES less than (400)
);
```

Now i am expecting since range partition is on store_id.So I will have 2 records in partition p0 for store_id 79 and 85 and 1 record in partition p3 for record having store_id 302.

But when I fire below query , I see different result

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME,SUBPARTITION_NAME, TABLE_ROWS,
 PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION,PARTITION_METHOD, PARTITION_EXPRESSION
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME='employee';
```

o/p:-

[image]

Here in above output I can see only 2 records for partition p0 but there is not record for partition p3.But there should be total three records.
2 records for partition p0 and 1 record for partition p3.
Why this above query on "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS" gives wrong result?

Comment: What benefit are you hoping to gain from `PARTITIONing`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [information_schema.partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-partitions-table.html) table explains,

> TABLE_ROWS
>
> The number of table rows in the partition.
>
> For partitioned InnoDB tables, the row count given in the TABLE_ROWS
> column is only an estimated value used in SQL optimization, and may
> not always be exact.

So, in your case the estimate is incorrect.